# Using a variable from a previous play along with patterns in the 'hosts' keyword of an Ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook.  It will eventually be used to execute SQL on a MySQL database.

```yaml
---
# This playbook sets a bunch facts/variables
# including mysql_config_master.
- import_playbook: init.yml

- name: Create Config Database
  hosts: newsp:!*:&{{ mysql_config_master }}
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: Debug MySql Config Master
      debug:
        var: mysql_config_master
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'mysql_config_master' is undefined

The error appears to be in '/home/red/GIT/ansible/playbooks/create_sp_config_db.yml': line 5, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Create sp_config Database
  ^ here
```

So I change my playbook to this:

```yaml
---
# This playbook sets a bunch facts/variables
# including mysql_config_master.
- import_playbook: init.yml

- name: Create Config Database
  hosts: newsp
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: Debug MySql Config Master
      debug:
        var: mysql_config_master
```

I get the expected output:

```json
TASK [Debug MySql Config Master] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 21 November 2023  14:06:13 -0800 (0:00:02.244)       0:00:22.827 ******
Tuesday 21 November 2023  14:06:13 -0800 (0:00:02.244)       0:00:22.824 ******
ok: [sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com] => {
    "mysql_config_master": "sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com"
}
ok: [sandbox-xo-dmz2.pl.example.com] => {
    "mysql_config_master": "sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com"
}
ok: [sandbox-xo-arb.pl.example.com] => {
    "mysql_config_master": "sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com"
}
ok: [sandbox-xo-rtp1.pl.example.com] => {
    "mysql_config_master": "sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com"
}
```

So `mysql_config_master` is defined.  What am I doing wrong?
I know I could add a `mysql_config_master` group and add my host
there and use `hosts: mysql_config_master`, but my boss thinks
that is a "terrible idea".

I could use a `when` clause like so:

```yaml
- name: Create Config Database
  hosts: newsp
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: Debug MySql Config Master
      debug:
        var: mysql_config_master
      when: inventory_hostname == mysql_config_master
```

But I'd preferred to set the hosts in the `hosts:` clause.

Here is the *init.yml* playbook.  I didn't write it and I would prefer to not use it but my employers insist that we need to use it.

*init.yml*:

```yaml
---
- name: Pre gather facts for all hosts
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

- name: Set variables based on the hostvars
  hosts: cluster,aws, monitor
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  roles:
    - roles/libs/set_sp_vars

- name: Set sp_srv based on the hostvars
  hosts: sp,newsp,monitor
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  roles:
    - roles/libs/set_sp_srv
```

Comment: `init.yml` is targeting `localhost` as `hosts`, right?

Comment: I'll post the init.yml playbook but I suggested not using this init.yml playbook and I thought I was going to be fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the second play does not have hosts to target yet, so it is clueless on where it should try to find the variable `mysql_config_master`.

You should explicitly point where the variable was defined, for example, in the `hostvars` of `a.specific.host.example.org` would translate to:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostvars['a.specific.host.example.org'].mysql_config_master }}"
```

If your `init.yml` targeted a group, and that your fact was defined with a `run_once: true`, causing the fact to be set on all the hosts of that group, you could do something like:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostvars[groups.group_name.0].mysql_config_master }}"
```

In your case, since you are targeting the group `all`, you could, then, do:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostvars[groups.all.0].mysql_config_master }}"
```

---

Given that `sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com` is part of the `all` group, the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mysql_config_master: sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com
      run_once: true


- hosts: "{{ hostvars[groups.all.0].mysql_config_master }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mysql_config_master
```

Would yield:

```yaml
PLAY [all] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **********************************************************
ok: [sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com]

PLAY [sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com] ************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com] => 
  mysql_config_master: sandbox-xo-dmz1.pl.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks B! That works great. Maybe someday I will be allowed to create a mysql_config_master group or even just to be allowed to set mysql_config_master in the group_vars.

Comment: BTW I found an odd annoyance with this solution.  Running `ansible-playbook` with `--list-hosts` will fail because `hostvars` is not defined. Other than that this works fine.